# Can I restore a backup which was on SQL Express to sql server server 2008 without any problems

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am going to do a customer SQL upgrade and they currently have SQL Express and I want to upgrade it to Microsoft SQL server 2008.

Will it be okay to restore the SQL Express backup to Microsoft SQL Server 2008?

Comment: This is like asking if you can take a windows backup and restore it on linux. Guess what, it isn't going to work. Mysql is completely different DBMS than sql server.

Comment: It might be much easier for you to re create the database in SQL Server 2008. How big is your database in mysql?

Answer (score 1):

First off, the comments seem to mention MySQL. I can see that you edited it to say SQL Express. If it is indeed MS SQL Express then yes, as SMM said it will work.

I have done this a few times before, and it worked just fine. Though rather than a backup/restore I would move the .mdf file.

This is done by detaching the DB from the Express instance and attaching it to the Server 2008 instance; this can be easily done via sqlcmd or the Studio Manager. The steps can vary based on systems(s) setup. As such, I did a google search to see if there existed a step by step guide for this rather than typing a bunch of scenarios as shots in the dark. There are a plethora of them:

I just Googled: move sql express .mdf to sql server 2008

I also found this and it would seem to be a good match for your situation and has good information:

http://www.mipsis.com/help/Moving%20SQL%20Express%20Database%20to%20SQL%20Server.pdf

Let me know how it goes, and if you need specific assistance with the process please follow up.

Answer (score 0):

I have done SQL Express to SQL 2000 and SQL 2005 successfully in the (distant) past. I am sure this will work. I don't remember any specific caveats other than making sure that you don't try to go from a later version of Express to an earlier version of SQL.